# Java: How to make use of class in one project to another

Tags: java

I am learning Java and I am interested in knowing that how to make use of a class in a project which does not contain it and is present in another project but on the same machine?

Comment: Wrap it in JAR and include it in classpath. Also most IDEs allow to include other projects in build-path.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get the class onto the class path.

At a more fundamental level the .class file just needs to be on the class path of the running application You can read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html about adding the class to the class path for the runtime and also javac compiler.

At a higher level, if you utilise some dependency management tool liked Maven or Gradle you can install the artifact on your local repository with an `mvn install` and then import it into your other project using the maven artefact coordinates as a `dependency` in your `pom.xml`.

This works well when running on the same machine. If you want to distribute the JAR you'd need to either publish to a public repository or copy the jar to the machine and install it to the local registry.

Alternatively, use your IDE such as eclipse to add the JAR from project A into the dependencies of project B